# RestKit Mapping and JSON serialization

Tags: arrays, json, serialization, restkit

I've got an issue with RestKit wrapping the serialization of my arrays with ( brackets instead of [ brackets.

Is there a way to customise/set the deliimter/wrapper character for a specific datatype?

I end up with this:

```
Media =     (
            {
        Description = Observation;
        IsPrimaryMedia = 0;
        Licence = "BY-NC-SA";
        MediaResourceId = "mediaresources/24";
    }
);
```

when what I'd really like is this:

```
Media =     [
            {
        Description = Observation;
        IsPrimaryMedia = 0;
        Licence = "BY-NC-SA";
        MediaResourceId = "mediaresources/24";
    }
];
```

I've tried to change the serializationMIMEType between Form and JSON to no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what was causing my serialization to add the non-JSON compliant () wrapper for an array rather than [], but to get around it, I passed the JSON string as RKObjectLoader params like this:

```
RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];

[manager sendObject:nil toResourcePath:theurl usingBlock:^(RKObjectLoader *loader) {

        NSDictionary *d = ... from parameters..

        NSError *e;
        NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:d options:0 error:&e];

        NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        loader.params = [RKRequestSerialization serializationWithData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] MIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];

    }];
```